# How to set cookie onclick for changing background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cookies, background

I try to change the background of a div onclick and preserved it with a cookie. Here is my code. Firstly I can't realize if my cookie has been set and secondly if I can change the background with the value of the cookie.

Can anyone help with an idea?

```
<div class="container">


<div class="col-md-6">

<div class="one"><a id="1" onClick="addcookie()" href="#">Fisrt Link</a></div>

</div>



<div class="col-md-6">

<div class="two"><a id="2" onClick="addcookie()" href="#">Second Link</a></div>

</div>




</div>
<script src=js/jquery-1.11.1.js></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<script>

var cookieName = 'cookie1';
function addcookie(){



    var date = new Date();
    var minutes = 5;
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));

    var idi = getDocumentById(this.id);

    var cookieValue = "http://path to image/image"+idi+".png";

    $.cookie(cookieName, cookieValue, { expires: date });

    $('.one').css('background', $.cookie('cookieName'));

}

</script>



<script src=js/bootstrap.js></script>
</body>
```

Comment: There's no native `getDocumentById()` function, perhaps you meant the `document.getElementById()` method?

Comment: one piece of advice: use dev tools of your browser to see the cookies being set: right-click > inspect element > Resources > Cookies (in most cases, Chrome for sure)

Comment: Are you trying to save a single cookie for both the divs...?

Comment: You might wanna use `localStorage` instead of cookies for something like this. Little less intrusive and does the job just fine

Comment: @George Thanks for the correction! I do not know what I was thinking! :-)

Comment: @TJ Yes it seems that I try to use a single cookie for both divs. Ιs this wrong? How can I manage multiple divs with cookies?

Comment: @webeno Thank you now I can see the cookie!

Comment: @NIKOSMOUSTAKAS What are you actually trying to do..? Save the current background of a `<div>` in cookies for future visits..? It seems there are many such `<div>`'s. Will all those share the same background..? If not, then you should set multiple cookies or look into how you can save an object in a single cookie. Your question as it is, is totally unclear.

Comment: @NIKOSMOUSTAKAS I rolled back your edit because it invalidates the existing answers (*Too late for editing*). If you want help with doing something simple based on an answer, You can comment below the answer asking for the same, Or try something by yourself... google is your friend. If you're stuck with something, then post a different question explaining what exactly you're trying to do, what you've tried, and what exactly is the challenge you're facing.

Comment: @TJ Ok I will try to make another question!

Comment: have you tried implementing my suggestions...?

Answer (score 0):

Other than what @George already pointed out in a comment (replace `getDocumentById()` - non-existent native function - with `document.getElementById()`), you'll also have to make sure that you're adding the image URL is coded properly, os instead of...

```
$('.one').css('background', $.cookie('cookieName'));
```

...do this...

```
$('.one').css('background', 'url("' + $.cookie(cookieName) + '")');
```

This is the proper CSS syntax for including background URL's is not...

```css
background:http://path to image/image.png
```

...but...

```
background:url("http://path to image/image.png");
```

...and because if you want to use a variable as a function's parameter, you have to omit the quotes around it, ie. `$.cookie('cookieName')` becomes `$.cookie(cookieName)`.

Additionally, `this.id` will only return the id of the element if you pass `this` as a parameter of your inline function as follows:

```
onClick="addcookie(this)"
```

...then reference the same in your function like this:

```
function addcookie(that)
```

...and use it like this:

```
var idi = that.id;
```

Here is a jsfiddle where you can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/yxj8w6d0/

**EDIT**: With a few little modifications (remove the `one` and `two` classed divs, and add `no-repeat` to the background) you have a neat little way of always only adding the background to the element in question, assuming it's what you actually wanted to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/yxj8w6d0/1/

**EDIT #2**: To get the images loaded if the cookie already exists, create another function that fires on document ready going through your links and checking them against the existing cookies, as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.container div a').each(function(){
        if ($.cookie(this.id))
            $(this).css('background', 'url("' + $.cookie(this.id) + '") no-repeat');
    });
});
```

I updated the above fiddle accordingly. Try it by clicking the links first, then running the script again - you'll see that the links will keep their background: http://jsfiddle.net/yxj8w6d0/2/

Comment: Also `this` will be set to `window`... either suggest to pass the reference in inline handler, or better suggest binding it separately..

Comment: Updated code

Because I want to change the div's background I used $('#c' + idi).css and it works! Βut when the change of the background has taken place, altough I see the cookie in > Resources > Cookies, by refreshing the page the background comes to the original state. What does this mean? That the cookie doesn't work?