# How to use cookies to save changes in background of a div for future visits

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, hyperlink, background

More specific question of

[How to set cookie onclick for changing background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442698/how-to-set-cookie-onclick-for-changing-background)

Because I want to change the div's background I used `$('#c' + idi).css...` and it works! Βut when the change of the background has taken place, altough I see the cookie in >

Resources > Cookies, by refreshing the page the background comes to the original state. What does this mean? That the cookie doesn't work?

My goal is to save the new background of the each div for future visits and because they do not share the same background I used this two lines

```
var cookieValue = "http://path" + idi + "path.png";
$('#c' + idi).css('background', 'url("' + $.cookie(cookieName) + '") no-repeat');
```

Can I use one cookie for multiple number of divs?

```
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div id="c1" class="one"><a id="1" onClick="addcookie(this)" href="#">first</a></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div id="c2" class="two"><a id="2" onClick="addcookie(this)" href="#">second</a></div>
</div>
</div>
<script src=js/jquery-1.11.1.js></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script>
var cookieName = 'cookie1';
function addcookie(that){
    var date = new Date();
    var minutes = 30;
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
    var idi = that.id;
    var cookieValue = "http://path" + idi + "path.png";
    $.cookie(cookieName, cookieValue, {
        expires: date
    });

    $('#c' + idi).css('background', 'url("' + $.cookie(cookieName) + '") no-repeat');

}

</script>
<script src=js/bootstrap.js></script>
</body>
```

Comment: you have no code to check for the cookie when page loads

Comment: Yes... You're not at all trying to read the cookies value and set the background accordingly when the page loads... And BTW, My comments to your previous question mentioned something about *trying something by yourself*... did you atleast google how to store an object in cookie... ah, never mind...

Comment: @TJ So, you tell me to check the value of the cookie in order to keep the background changes after the refreshing? But how to track the ids of the divs that have been clicked?

Comment: @NIKOSMOUSTAKAS First of all, you should store an object in cookie - Whose keys are the `id` of clicked `<div>`'s and values are the respective backgrounds. Then, When the page loads, you should check whether any cookie exists or not, if it exists, read the value and set the backgrounds of `<div>`'s whose `id` is present in the object with respective value... Plenty of information regarding how to do each of these steps are already available out there in the internet... good luck.. :)

Comment: Oh and by the way I suggest deleting your previous question since it is not going to be useful for anyone... neither is this one... Please ask questions when you're stuck with a specific problem while trying to achieve your goal, rather than asking how to achieve the goal itself...

Comment: @TJ In this case I didn't know the procedure that I must follow. With the above comment you help me to go on. I didn't expect to give the solution ready but to guide me.

Comment: @NIKOSMOUSTAKAS I told so only because you can post better questions in the future.. :)